# using flow_from_directory for training and validation, without augmentation

Tags: keras, data-augmentation

I am training a simple CNN with Nt=148 + Nv=37 images for training and validation respectively. I used the `ImageGenerator.flow_from_directory()` method because I plan to use data augmentation in the future, but for the time being I don't want any data augmentation. I just want to read the images from disk one by one (and each exactly once, this is primarily important for the validation) to avoid loading all of them in memory.

But the following makes me think that something different than expected is happening:

1. the training and validation accuracy achieve values which do not resemble a fraction with 148 or 37 as the denominator. Actually trying to estimate a reasonable denominator from a submultiple of the deltas, leads to numbers much bigger than 148 (about 534 or 551, see below (*) why I think they should be multiples of 19) and of 37
2. verifying all predictions on both the training and and validation datasets (with a separate program, which reads the validation directory only once and doesn't use the above generators), shows a number of fails which is not exactly (1-val_acc)*Nv as I would expect

(*) Lastly I found that the batch size I used for both is 19, so I expect that I am providing 19*7=133 or 19*8=152 training images per epoch and 19 or 38 images as the validation set at each epoch end.

By the way: is it possible to use the `model.fit_generator()` with generators built from the `ImageGenerator.flow_from_directory()` to achieve:
- no data augmentation
- both generators should respectively supply all images to the training process and to the validation process exactly once per epoch
- shuffling is fine, and actually desired, so that each epoch runs different

Meanwhile I am orienting myself to set the batch size equal to the validation set length (i.e. 37). Being it a divider of the training set numerosity, I think it should work out the numbers.

But still I am unsure if the following code is achieving the requirement "no data augmentation at all"

```
valid_augmenter = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

val_batch_size = 37

train_generator = train_augmenter.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=val_batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode='grayscale',
    follow_links=True )

validation_generator = valid_augmenter.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height,img_width),
    batch_size=val_batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode='grayscale',
    follow_links=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in your situation.
First of all, that amount of images is quite low. **Scrape** a lot more images and use augmentation.
Second, I have seen typical fractions are:

from the total data:

80% for train

20% for validation.

Put the images you select in folders with that proportion.

Third, you can check if your code generates data if you put this line in your `flow_from_directory` call, after the last line (and put a comma after that last line):

```
save_to_dir='folder_to_see_augmented_images'
```

Then run the model (compile, and then fit) and check the contents of the `save_to_dir` folder.